# Checking Python Boto SimpleDB for empty result set

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-simpledb

How can I check to see if the result set is empty when querying SimpleDB in Boto 2? Can I check it before it goes into the for loop?

```
rs = dom.select(query)

for j in rs:
  ...do something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ResultSet returned is an iterator. You can check whether it has any value with `next()` which fetches the first element from the cursor if there are any. If it is empty, it raises `StopIteration` error.

```
rs = dom.select(query)

try:
    rs.next()
except StopIteration:
    print('Empty ResultSet')
```

Answer (score 0):

`rs` is a Python object, can you just do this?

```
rs = dom.select(query)
if len(rs) > 0:
    for j in rs:
      ...do something
else:
    print("resultset is empty")
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get:
`TypeError: object of type 'SelectResultSet' has no len()`